# Combine IIF and select statement to pull data from different tables

Tags: sql, foxpro

I'm trying to do a SQL query using `DBF Commander` on a FoxPro database that has to pull the quantity ordered and weight from another table and multiple them together to get the total weight.

When I run this is gives me an error that I'm missing a comma.  If I encapsulate the `IIF(select)` statement like this:  `IIF((select ...) > 8000,"T","F")` I get `) missing function`.

Is the `select` within the `IIF()` not a valid operation?

```
select 
HT.ordnum,
IIF((select sum(qtyord*weight) from 'DT.dbf' as DT where DT.ordnum = HT.ordnum as TotalWeight) >= 8000, "Big load", "Little Load")
from 'HT.dbf' as HT where HT.ordnum like '%12111%'
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and there is no `IIF()` function in standard SQL) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Typically you want a `CASE` expression

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I wish I hadn't heard it either...

Comment: Any time the error message mentions parentheses in any way, count the opening and closing parens.  Your 3rd line has two opening parens, and three closing parens.

Comment: @AndyLester thanks.  It was a typo when I was putting it here.  I verified the parens.

Comment: That's a great example of why you should always always always cut & paste rather than retyping.

Comment: Sorry had some file paths that were absurdly long and when I truncated them here I accidentally backspaced or deleted the parens.

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL would like look this:

```
SELECT HT.ordnum,
    CASE WHEN SUM(qtyord.*weight) > 8000 THEN 'Big load' ELSE 'Little load' END
FROM HT.dbf as HT 
WHERE HT.ordnum like '%12111%'
GROUP BY HT.ordnum
```

Fox Pro is an older product, so I'm not sure how it's particular SQL dialect will make you change this.

Comment: It looks like there is a "DO CASE" "END CASE" in FoxPro.  Since the qtyorder*weight is in the DT.dbf and not in HT.dbf, how do I make it use that DB instead.  Not sure you can do a case when from 'DT.dbf'.

Answer (score 0):

Try after Removing 'as TotalWeight'

Answer (score 0):

In FoxPro, you can probably do something like the following.
Difficult to tell though since you did not provide sample data and a description of the expected result.

```
SELECT HT.ordnum, IIF(sum(DT.qtyord*DT.weight) >= 8000, "Big Load", "Little Load") ;
    FROM HT ;
    Left Join DT On DT.ordnum = HT.ordnum ;
    GROUP BY HT.ordnum ;
    where HT.ordnum like '%12111%'
```

NB FoxPro is a DBase/XBase DBMS, iif() is a built-in function, and ";" is a line-continuation

Answer (score 0):

So, since your HT.OrdNum = DT.OrdNum, but you are not really pulling any other value from HT, you can completely get away with just querying from the DT table.  In this case, I am pre-querying the TD table, summing the QtyOrd * Weight and grouping by the ordNum.  Applying the same where to filter out just those orders will give you one record per ordNum.

From that, its just a simple outer query against the inner pre-query (PQ alias)

```
SELECT
      PQ.OrdNum,
      IIF( PQ.TotalWeight > 8000, 'Big load', 'Little load' ) LoadSize
   from
      ( select 
              DT.ordnum,
              sum(DT.qtyord * DT.weight ) TotalWeight 
           from 
              DT
           where
              DT.ordnum like '%12111%'
           group by
              DT.ordnum ) PQ
```